# When should we consider changing syncDelay?

Tags: mongodb

We are seeing periods where flushing to disk takes far too long, and the DB locks up.

```
Tue Mar 11 09:42:49.818 [DataFileSync] flushing mmaps took 75264ms  for 46 files
```

We are modifying quite a lot of data every 30 seconds in a batch job, and it seems to me that it would make sense to sync to disk every 30 seconds instead of 60 to spread the IO load better.

However, the MongoDB manual (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/parameters/#param.syncdelay) is very clear and at the same time completely useless:

> In almost every situation you should not set this value and use the default setting.

So, can anyone describe scenarios where it is a good idea to modify the syncDelay?

Comment: Wouldn't a lower value actually heat up IO even more? Though it could work and this scenario seems legit

Comment: It is not the same data that is updated every 30 seconds, so I would believe the changeset should be approx half.

Comment: Yeah, this sounds like a legit scenario to modify it